# Проблема с настройкой GRUB. Внести Windows в загрузчик

Tags: linux, windows, grub, dual-boot, manjaro

Установил Manjaro Linux параллельно с Windows. По невнимательности установил загрузчик Manjaro на диск C:, туда, где уже был загрузчик Windows. При буте С: запускается GRUB. Необходимо либо перенести GRUB на другой диск, не переустанавливая систему (ибо установилась с 6 раза, задрало уже), либо настроить GRUB таким образом, чтобы из него можно было запустить и Windows, и Manjaro. 
Знаю, что надо чинить файл /boot/grub/grub.cfg, вот только настроить его по-нормальному не получается, при буте выдает ошибку "Invalid sector size 65535" (что, по мнению людей на форумах, означает неверно прописанное коренное устройство)

Мой код в grub.cfg:

```
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/451_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows 7" {
set root=(hd0,msdos1)
chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
```

(не первый и не последний вариант)

Помогите, пожалуйста)) #новичок

Answer (score 2):

Этот файл не надо менять, надо просто запустить `update-grub` в каталоге `grub.d`.

Comment: *в каталоге grub.d* — совершенно излишнее требование.

Comment: Уже пробовал, увы, не дает результатов. Отображается лишь "Manjaro Linux" и настройки для него. Другие варианты?

Comment: @Freewalkr, для начала вам, вероятно, стоит «вернуть назад» все правки, которые вы вносили в конфигурацонные файлы *grub-а*.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin Каким образом? Скажем, пресловутый update-grub подойдет?

Comment: @Freewalkr, «пресловутый update-grub», создаёт конф. файл `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` на основе информации из каталога `/etc/grub.d`. если вы ничего не меняли в этом каталоге, то «возвращать назад» нечего. для начала стоит убедиться, что у вас всё ещё установлен пакет os-prober. приведите, пожалуйста, вывод команды `sudo os-prober` (её запускает «пресловутый update-grub» для распознания других операционных систем). // p.s. чтобы мне приходили оповещения о ваших комментариях, упомяните меня явно: `@alex` будет достаточно.

Comment: @alex Эту команду просто запускать? У меня она не дает вывода.

Comment: @Freewalkr, если `os-prober` не даёт вывода, то, значит, не обнаруживает других установленных операционных систем. это может происходить по множеству причин, но наиболее вероятно, по-моему, то, что раздел, где расположены «системные» файлы *ms/windows*, не имеет boot-флага. вам, как начинающему, вероятно, будет проще его установить с помощью граф. программы gparted.

Comment: @Freewalkr, кстати, вот ещё есть программка, которая, возможно, вам поможет: [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)

Answer (score 0):

У меня grub2, настроено так:

```
menuentry 'Windows' {
        set root=hd1,1
        ntldr /bootmgr
    }
```

Comment: "Не найдена команда ntldr"

Comment: Манжаро похож на арч, вот какие способы нашел на их вики:
    
    1. menuentry "Windows" {
        chainloader (hd0,2)+1
}

    2. menuentry "Windows XP" {
        set root=hd0,2
        ntldr /ntldr
}

    3. menuentry "Windows 7" {
        set root=hd0,3
        ntldr /bootmgr
}

Comment: Первый пример сейчас опробую, 2 и 3 - еще раз, команду ntldr он не находит.

Comment: Версия виндовс какая?

Comment: Семерка. Опробовал 1 способ. Опять родное-любимое "Invalid sector size 65535".

Comment: У вас случайно не груб-ефи установлен? 
Попробуйте так: 
`menuentry 'windows' {
        insmod part_gpt
        set root='(hd0,gpt2)' # efi раздел на sda2
        chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}`

Comment: Именно ЕФИ!! Забыл уточнить! Сейчас опробую!

Comment: Инвалид сектор... Так, а ведь " # efi раздел на sda2" - это комментарий, его надо было стереть?

Comment: сотрите и  укажите правильный раздел, где лежит виндовс.

Comment: Вот это - один из самых интересных вопросов. Как правильно его указывать? Как понять, что писать: gpt, msdos, просто цифру?

Comment: покажите результат команды `fdisk -l`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40790/discussion-between-freewalkr-and-dmitry-erohin).

Comment: `submenu "Windows" {
 regexp -s root '\((.+)\)' "$cmdpath"
 chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}`